# Cannot Use WorkMail Allies Addresses in iOS Mail

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, smtp, imap, amazon-workmail

I have an organisation set up in AWS WorkMail with several custom domains. Some users have several aliases that make use of said domains. In the WorkMail website there's no problem at all sending an email from any of their associated aliases. However, in iOS when they try to send via an alias address, it'll send successfully but always from the default email address. This happens no matter how they setup the account. Be it an Exchange server or IMAP/SMTP and adding the aliases manually.

Does anyone have any idea what we could do or a potential work around? It's very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is still no comprehensive solution for this but I found a work-around using the iOS Gmail App and SES:

1. Install the Gmail App on the iOS Device.
2. In AWS Console, setup SES and create a set of SMTP Credentials with permissions to send on behalf of the WorkMail account.
3. Login to Gmail using a web browser, the under `Send mail as:`, which can be found under `Inbox Settings` [sic] -`Accounts and Import` tab, enter the SES SMTP credentials.
4. Use the Gmail iOS App to send email. The `From:` field will allow you to pick any of the aliases created using `Send mail as:`

Of note:

- The native iOS Mail app does not have access to Google's `Accounts and Import` configuration, so you have to use the Gmail iOS app.
- WorkMail's SMTP endpoint is very strict about Sender Identity, so you need to use SES instead which is designed for programmatic use and therefore allows more flexibility.